# Why people were afraid to call Kirin "Saiho"?

Tags: the-twelve-kingdoms

In Episode 14, Half-demon rat explains how whole 12 kingdoms formed and their emperors and Kirins. He also says:

> the Kirin's official name is Saiho, but people are afraid to call them Saiho, so calling them taiho has become the norm.

However he didn't tell why. So my question is why people were afraid to call kirin "Saiho"?